# Database Searching with multiple textboxes in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am developing a "cv save and search application" with using c# and windows forms. My problem is when I enter both the phone number field and the email field at the same time it doesn't do a correct search.

In theory when I enter wrong email and enter correct phone number, the data gridview should not display any information. But because of if and else statements running from up to down, if phone number is true the program does not control e-mail field. How can I fix this?

Note: I changed all "else if" statements to "if" statements but it did not work.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO9qP.png)

[Scrensshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkYhB.png)

my codes:

```cs
private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///search in databese
    if (textBox_Name.Text != "")
    {
        showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE NAME LIKE'" + textBox_Name.Text + "%'");
    }
    else if (textBox_Surname.Text != "")
    {
        showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE SURNAME LIKE'" + textBox_Surname.Text + "%'");
    }
    else if (textBox_Id.Text != "")
    {
        showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE ID LIKE'" + textBox_Id.Text + "%'");
    }
    else if (textBox_Phone.Text != "")
    {
        showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE PHONE LIKE'" + textBox_Phone.Text + "%'");
    }
    else if (textBox_Email.Text != "")
    {
        showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE EMAIL LIKE'" + textBox_Email.Text + "%'");
    }
    else if (comboBox_Gender.Text != "")
    {
        if (comboBox_Gender.Text == "Male")
        {
            showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE GENDER LIKE'" + 0 + "%'");
        }
        else if (comboBox_Gender.Text == "Female")
        {
            showData("SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE GENDER LIKE'" + 1 + "%'");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a information");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an example of why you need to work out the logic first and then write code to implement that logic specifically. None of those queries you construct contains more than one filter so how can you possibly filter by multiple columns? Also, you're using `if...else if`, so as soon as you find one filter field populated you stop looking. There's no way that you'd write code to do those things if had the logic determined first. You might still have trouble writing the code you need but you wouldn't write code that does nonsensical things. Don't write any code until you know what it has to do.

Comment: Compare your program with answer of Olivier Jacot-Descombes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute several filters at once, then you must include all the filters in a single SELECT command and construct a WHERE clause dynamically. I do this by adding terms to a `StringBuilder`.

By using some helper functions the task becomes easier. They can be either implemented as local functions (inside `search_Click`) or as separate methods.

```cs
static void AddLikeWithAnd(StringBuilder filter, string columnName, string value)
{
    if (value != "") {
        if (filter.Length > 0) {
            filter.Append(" AND ");
        }
        filter.Append(columnName).Append(" LIKE ").Append(AsSqlString(value + "%"));
    }

}

static string AsSqlString(string s)
{
    return "'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

The first one adds the term conditionally, depending on whether the text box is empty or not. It also joins the terms with `AND`. The second functions creates a SQL string literal by taking care of escaping single quotes with double quotes.

With these helper methods you can write:

```cs
private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filter = new StringBuilder();
    AddLikeWithAnd(filter, "[NAME]", textBox_Name.Text);
    AddLikeWithAnd(filter, "SURNAME", textBox_Surname.Text);
    AddLikeWithAnd(filter, "ID", textBox_Id.Text);
    AddLikeWithAnd(filter, "PHONE", textBox_Phone.Text);
    AddLikeWithAnd(filter, "EMAIL", textBox_Email.Text);

    string genderValue = comboBox_Gender.Text.ToLower() switch {
        "male" => "0",
        "female" => "1",
        _ => ""
    };
    AddLikeWithAnd(filter, "GENDER", genderValue);

    if (filter.Length > 0) {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE " + filter.ToString();
        showData(sql);
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a information");
    }
}
```

I also escaped the column name `NAME` with square brackets as this is a reserved word in some SQL dialects. E.g. SQL-Server and Access use square brackets, MySQL uses back-ticks and Oracle double quotes as escape characters.

With `textBox_Name.Text = "Joe's Pub"` and `textBox_Email.Text = "joe"` I get this SQL command:

```sql
SELECT * FROM BILGILER WHERE [NAME] LIKE 'Joe''s Pub%' AND EMAIL LIKE 'joe%'
```

Note that you can use LIKE only with text columns. If e.g. `ID` and `GENDER` are number columns, this will not work. And also the values must not be enclosed in single quotes then.

---

My answers solves the *"Searching with multiple textboxes"* problem; however, another fundamental problem is inserting parameter values with string concatenation instead of using parametrized queries. Many answers were given and many articles were written to this subject, so I will not integrate it in my answer.

See: [C# using parametrized query](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+using+parametrized+query)

---

I used newer C# features like the switch expression. If you work with an older Framework version, you might have to add the `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` tag to your project file. See: [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Comment: In general, the idea here is good. But we should still be using parameterized queries. rather than appending user input. Even if we set aside the SQL Injection Attack aspect of it (it's a Win Forms app after all), we're not going to be able to take advantage of existing query plans unless this is properly parameterized. This pattern of building up dynamic SQL is a little tricky to get right, that's why there's libraries like [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com/) to make this much easier.

Comment: @mason, `s.Replace("'", "''")` makes injection attacks impossible. This would have to be done in `showData` whose code we do not not know. But yes, you are right; however, teaching a beginner too many things at once will not yield fruit. Using an ORM and construct the query with LINQ would be even better.

Comment: I understand the desire to not overload with information, but forming queries with values that aren't parameterized is something that shouldn't be ignored in the name of simplicity: it's an important point to convey that it's the right thing to do. And it's not even that hard: every time you add a filter to the SQL command, add a corresponding parameter to the parameters collection. That protects from SQL Injection Attacks and helps the queries run correctly (by taking advantage of existing query plans). That's not too much for a beginner.